# How to get url of current theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The doc says use that

```
<?php bloginfo(‘template_url’);?>
```

but the output is just a theme folder not the complete url.

NB my task is to get url of a php file in my theme folder

Answer (score 12):

If you are using a child theme, the other solutions won't work, it'll give you the directory of the parent theme.  For child themes use this:

```
<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it. 'stylesheet_directory' is the way if you are using a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try get_included_files()

It will list everything down but it will use the Filesystem path not the URL

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code for getting current theme url in wordpress

```
<?php bloginfo(‘template_url’);?>
```

or

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```